# Intelligent crawler that can prioritize sources based on keywords?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to create a webcrawler that continuously crawls the web looking for webpages that contain certain keywords. There are a lot of open source solutions for this (Nutch, Scrapy et cetera), but I need an intelligent one that can prioritize 'rich' sources.

I want the bot to start at a certain page, f.e. http://www.dmoz.org, extract all links and continue scraping them. Now if the page contains a certain keyword, f.e. 'foo', it should send this url to a database.

Now, here comes the hard part. If I create and run a bot like this it can take ages before the spider finds new pages containing the specified keywords, since it's crawling the whole web. The process would be dramatically faster if the spider could identify on what domain it often finds the keywords so these can be crawled more often.

Is there an open source solution for this?

So far I've looked at Nutch and Scrapy. Nutch looks to be the best option for what I need, but I don't have any experience with Java and I can't find any specific documentation about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this yet, but I assume you can do this in Nutch by controlling how you score the outlinks. If your current page contains your keywords, you could give a higher score to outlinks for that page.

An implementation of a plugin that extends ScoringFilter is given in http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2012/01/nutchgora-scoring-and-indexing-plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to work with a Java based solution, you might want to have a look at [Infant](http://www.infant-ir.info/). Infant is a micro web crawling library. It's not an open source project, but is completely free, even for commercial use. You should be able to write your own plug-in for Infant, to control the order in which Infant maintains its URL queue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still looking for something similar you can use one of our very similar open source software which is on

[Github Link](https://github.com/theupscale/context-parser)

It works on the context based rule engine where you can assign any keyword or text a single value from 0 to 9 as weight, and when it will parse it, will let you crawl what you want

It is based on ROR

MYSQL, MONGO, and Ubuntu 14.04 with other regular gems which you can manage yourself,